# django server doesn't load css when it is run

Tags: python, css, django, django-templates, django-admin

I have all the static files, but for some reason only the normal html loads with no css. I have tried using collectstatic and creating a new project but it doesn't work on any.  STATIC_URL is also specified along with static in the url.py . Nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Please include your code here so that we can help you out. Also, you might want to read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Comment: Sry , a newbie to web dev and django . I tried to setup my project as my friend's(his is working properly) even he couldnt fix the issue. Heres the link to its git could you please look into it, I am sure its something silly I might have missed out. Thanks in advance. [link](https://github.com/kewalkishang/Django_Basics)

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais I think it has to do with my system configuration . Because the same project works fine on a different system .

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your DEBUG is set to False and did not mention any staticfiles dir.
Okay, update your settings.py as below:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_my_proj"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn", "static_root")
```

Now, that you have done that make dir called `static_my_proj`, at the same level where your `manage.py` file is.

Okay, now create new dir called `static_cdn` just one level up, i.e. one level up to `manage.py` file.

Now, create dir called `static_root` inside `static_cdn` and that is all you have to do. Make sure you run `python manage.py collectstatic`

NOTE:

`static_my_proj` is for development or `DEBUG = True` and `static_cdn` is for production or `DEBUG = True`. handy, right?

Also, you can add media file the same way, just add,

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn", "media_root")
```

and make new dir called media_root under static_cdn.

Set `DEBUG = True` first and test it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hey, this was the first this I tried when i ran into the problem . DEBUG was True from the very beginning. Even STATICFILES_DIRS is mentioned. I tried out the exact steps as you mentioned again, still the same problem . Is there anything else I may be missing out?

Comment: @kewalkishan please provide your tech-stack.

Comment: I am not too sure what you are asking for. but Django, bootstrap, SQLite.

Comment: I was asking for Django version. You can find it by typing command **pip freeze**.

Comment: Oh, its django 1.11.6 and python 3.6